# ¿Diferencia entre utilizar find o hacer un for igualando lo que quieres encontrar?

Tags: c++

Con for:

```
int encontrarNombre(string nombre) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Vnombres.size(); i++){
        if (Vnombres[i].nombre == nombre)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Con find:

```
bool encontrarNombre(string nombre) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Vnombres.size(); i++){
        if (nombre.find(Vnombres[i]) != string::npos)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

¿Por qué con *find* si tengo: **Pepe** y **FakePepe** me devuelve que está repetido porque **FakePepe** contiene la palabra **Pepe**  pero con el for me devuelve como que no está repetido?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Por qué con find si tengo: Pepe y FakePepe me devuelve que está repetido porque FakePepe contiene la palabra Pepe pero con el for me devuelve como que no está repetido?

Porque `find` sirve para buscar elementos dentro de un array... en este caso, subcadenas dentro de la cadena principal, mientras que el operador de comparación evalúa si ambos elementos son iguales

Por eso `std::string::find` te devuelve un `size_t` que representa la posición dentro de la cadena principal donde se encuentra la subcadena:

```
std::string a = "Pepe";
std::string b = "FakePepe";

std::cout << b.find(a); // imprime 4
```

Ya que como podemos ver:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
 F  a  k  e  P  e  p  e \0
             ^
             La subcadena 'Pepe' empieza en la posición 4
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!